# Perfect forwarding for void and non-void returning functions

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, rvalue-reference

Previously I was using a macro to measure the time a function call took whenever I wanted to quickly check that. Now, with C++11 available, I would like to finally remove that ugly peace of preprocessor code and replace it with something like this:

```
template <typename Functor, typename ... Args>
auto measure(Functor f, Args && ... args)
    -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ret = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - now).count();
    std::cout << "Time elapsed: " << elapsed << "ms" << std::endl;

    return ret;
}
```

Which works fine for functions that return something (i.e. not `void`). So I felt like I needed an overload for `void` functions - but you cannot overload a function just on return type.

I tried to walk around this problem using some template magic, but to no avail; the compiler still complains that the function `measure` is defined two times:

```
template <
    typename Functor, typename ... Args,
    typename ReturnType = typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_void<
            typename std::result_of<Functor(Args...)>::type
        >::value,
        typename std::result_of<Functor(Args...)>::type
    >::type
>
ReturnType measure(Functor f, Args && ... args)
{
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ret = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - now).count();
    std::cout << "Time elapsed: " << elapsed << "ms" << std::endl;

    return ret;
}

template <
    typename Functor, typename ... Args,
    typename ReturnType = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_void<
            typename std::result_of<Functor(Args...)>::type
        >::value
    >::type
>
ReturnType measure(Functor f, Args && ... args)
{
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - now).count();
    std::cout << "Time elapsed: " << elapsed << "ms" << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a way around this?

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the function I am now using thanks to R. Martinho Fernandes:

```
template <typename Functor, typename ... Args>
auto measure(Functor f, Args && ... args)
    -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    struct scoped_timer
    {
        scoped_timer() : now_(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()) {}
        ~scoped_timer()
        {
            auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<
                    std::chrono::milliseconds
                >(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - now_).count();
            std::cout << "Time elapsed: " << elapsed << "ms" << std::endl;
        }

        private:
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point const now_;
    } scoped_timer;

    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: See http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html#evolution

Comment: Elegant [idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17748197/1137388) (by [R. Martinho Fernandes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes)). The only change I would make would be placing `~scoped_timer()`'s code in a `try-catch` block that swallows any exception thrown. Semantically, I believe that it makes sense to not report the time that `f` takes to run if it doesn't complete successfully. Unfortunately, this is not so obvious regarding possible exceptions thrown by `<<`. Would an old `printf` be a better alternative (regarding exception safety)? I don't know.

Comment: @CassioNeri: `try-catch` inside a destructor would only catch exceptions thrown inside the destructor body (`operator<<(ostream&, x)` except that these don't ordinarily throw in case of error), they won't even notice exceptions that cause the destructor to be called during unwinding.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that default template arguments don't make for different templates, the same way that default function arguments don't make for different overloads. There are some ways around this, and I described them in my [*Remastered enable_if*](https://web.archive.org/web/20190920112547/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html#evolution) article.

However, I would not do that. I would simply take advantage of the fact that in generic code you can "`return` void", and use RAII to print out the elapsed time:

```
template <typename Functor, typename ... Args>
auto measure(Functor f, Args && ... args)
    -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    scoped_timer timer;
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

The `scoped_timer` class can be written trivially: save `now` in the constructor, and compute and output `elapsed` in the destructor.

Comment: Actually, I have done something similar to this before, and I just dropped the result value altogether, having `measure` return the elapsed time instead.

Comment: Your article is an incredibly interesting read. Thank you. I'd like to still return the value the function originally returns, but your solution serves just fine for this.