# Avoiding Repetition For SFINAE Differentiating Between void and Non-void Return Types

Tags: c++, c++11, void, sfinae, result-of

Some generic code manipulating functions, need to operate differently depending on whether a function has a return value or not. E.g., borrowing a problem from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748059/perfect-forwarding-for-void-and-non-void-returning-functions), say we need to write a `time_it` function takes a function and some arguments, runs it, and prints the elapsed time. The following code can do this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

template<class Fn, typename ...Args>
auto time_it(Fn fn, Args &&...args) ->  
    typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_void<typename std::result_of<Fn(decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...)>::type>::value,
        typename std::result_of<Fn(decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...)>::type>::type
{   
    const auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto const res = fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    const auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "elapsed " << (end - start).count() << std::endl;
    return res;
}   

template<class Fn, typename ...Args>
auto time_it(Fn fn, Args &&...args) -> 
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_void<typename std::result_of<Fn(decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...)>::type>::value,
        void>::type                                                                                                                                                                                      
{   
    const auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    const auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "elapsed " << (end - start).count() << std::endl;
}   

int main()
{   
    time_it([](double x){return std::cos(x);}, 3.0);
    time_it([](double x){}, 3.0);
}
```

As can be seen, there is a difference between the cases of the function returning a value or not. In the former case, the value must be stored, the elapsed time printed, and the value returned; in the latter case, after printing the elapsed time, nothing more needs to be done.

The question is how to deal with both case:

1. The above code uses [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`is_void`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_void), but the first (cumbersome in itself) argument to `is_void` is repeated as the last argument to `enable_if` - this is cumbersome and [smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), esp. as much of the body is repeated.
2. The aforementioned answer bypasses the problem by having the elapsed time being printed as the byproduct of a destructor of some elapsed-timer class being called. It's a nice idea, but in more complex uses would lead to convoluted code (substantial work is done in a destructor of some separate class - it's not a natural flow).

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could isolate the invoke-and-store code:

```
template<class R>
struct invoke_and_store_t {
  std::experimental::optional<R> ret;
  template<class F, class...Args>
  invoker_t&& operator()(F&& f, Args&&...args)&& {
    ret.emplace( std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...) );
    return std::move(*this);
  }
  R&& get()&&{ return std::move( *ret ) ); }
  template<class F>
  auto chain(F&& f)&&{
    return [r = std::move(*this).get(),f=std::move<F>(f)](auto&&...args)mutable
    {
      return std::move(f)(std::move(r), decltype(args)(args)...);
    };
  }
};
template<>
struct invoke_and_store_t<void> {
  template<class F, class...Args>
  invoker_t&& operator()(F&& f, Args&&...args)&& {
    std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return std::move(*this);
  }
  void get()&&{}
  template<class F>
  auto chain(F&& f)&&{
    return [f=std::move<F>(f)](auto&&...args)mutable{
      return std::move(f)(decltype(args)(args)...);
    };
  }
};
template<class F, class...Args, class R=std::decay_t<std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>>>
auto invoke_and_store(F&& f, Args&&...args) {
  return invoke_and_store_t<R>{}(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Arg>(args)...);
}
```

now your code becomes:

```
template <class R, class Fn, class... Args>
R time_it(tag<R>, Fn&& fn, Args&&... args)
{
  const auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  auto&& res = invoke_and_store(
    std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...
  );
  const auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::cout << "elapsed " << (end - start).count() << std::endl;
  return std::move(res).get();
}
```

which now has the same body for the two cases.  I factored out the problem of storing the return value (or not) into a helper, thus making the code that wants to deal with it not have to worry about it.

I also included `chain`, which takes a function object and either passes it the previous return value as the first argument, or doesn't, depending on if the previous return value was void.  I find that pattern pretty common in monad/functor-like code.

```
template<class A, class B>
auto then( A&& a, B&& b ) {
  return [a = std::forward<A>(a), B=std::forward<B>(b)](auto&&...args)mutable{
    return
      invoke_and_store(std::move(a))
      .chain(std::move(b))(decltype(args)(args)...);
  };
}
```

`then(a,b)(...)` calls `a()` then `b(a(),...)` or `a()` then `b(...)` depending on what `a()` returns.

Comment: @AmiTavory Changed it to use `std::experimental::optional`, which can be replaced with `boost::optional`, because of exception-safety concerns I spotted.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes all you need is a simple tag type:

```
template <class > struct tag { };
```

You can dispatch your `time_it` based on a wrapped result type:

```
template <class Fn, class... Args, class R = std::result_of_t<Fn&&(Args&&...)>>
R time_it(Fn fn, Args&&... args)
{
    return time_it(tag<R>{}, fn, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And then we just have overloads for the `void` and non-`void` versions:

```
template <class R, class Fn, class... Args>
R time_it(tag<R>, Fn fn, Args&&... args)
{
    const auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto const res = fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    const auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "elapsed " << (end - start).count() << std::endl;
    return res;    
}

template <class Fn, class... Args>
void time_it(tag<void>, Fn fn, Args&&... args)
{
    const auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    const auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "elapsed " << (end - start).count() << std::endl;
}
```

---

Of course, would be especially nice if [regular void](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0146r1.html) gets approved - at which point we wouldn't even need the special case at all!

Comment: Thanks also for the link to regular void!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some helper struct would do the trick?

```
template <class T>
struct enable_if_not_void: enable_if<!is_void<T>::value, T> { };
```

And usage:

```
template<class Fn, typename ...Args>
auto time_it(Fn fn, Args &&... args) -> typename enable_if_not_void<typename std::result_of<Fn(Args &&...)>::type>::type {
  //...
}
```

Comment: `Fn(decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...)` -> `Fn(Args...)`

Comment: Don't need `decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...)` that's just `Args&&...`